# How can I update a specific value in this array? (php)

Tags: php, arrays, updating

I have the following array, `$cart` which is structured like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sku] => TEST1
            [size] => s
            [qty] => 1
        )

)
```

how can I update the qty to 2 directly using php and not using a foreach loop (nb. assume I have the index value (0) already).

Thanks

Comment: *(reference)* http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$array[0]['qty'] = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something here, if you already know you want to update index 0:

```
$foo[0]['qty'] = 2;
```